# Int64_t aka long long acts as int32_t and overflows at 2^31

Tags: c++, data-type, print

I have an `int64_t` variable. When I add another `int64_t` variable

and convert it to a double to print it on the serial monitor, it acts as if it was a `int32_t` variable. This is the program:

```cpp
int64_t a = 1 << 31;
double b = static_cast<double>(a);
Serial.println(b);
```

The output on the serial monitor is `-2147483648.00`.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1 << 31` is interpreted by the compiler as `(int)1 << (int)32`.
See [the implicit types of integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal). The
rules of usual arithmetic conversions state that no implicit conversion
is performed in this case. The result is then computed as an `int`, and
it overflows. Note that this is undefined behavior. The assignment
`int64_t a = ...` converts the (already overflowed) result to the wider
type, without changing its value.

You probably want to write something like:

```cpp
int64_t a = 1LL << 31;
```

Comment: even  `uint32_t a = 1UL << 31;` would do the trick to interpret `0x80000000` as a positive number.  BTW, on a *real* arduino, where the native int is an `int16_t` you get `1<<31 == 0`